# how to submit datetime parameter to a WCF REST service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, rest

I have a WCF Data service operation :

```
[WebGet]
public bool isContractUpToDate(string contractId, string lastmodifiedDate);
```

but I don't know how to call this service from a .NET client application and how I can call this operation from Internet Explorer.
I'm looking for some examples.

Comment: Why is `lastmodifiedDate` typed as `string` instead of `DateTime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer to my question.
to invoke the operation from the browser, I use :

```
   http://localhost:8080/service/ctrService.svc/isContractUpToDate?contractId='1'&lastmodifieddate='2012/02/04 00:00:00'
```

and to do it from a .NET client, I use :

```
    IEnumerable<bool> resp = service.Execute<bool>(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/pricingservice/PricingDataService.svc/isContractUpToDate?contractId='1'&" +"lastmodifieddate='"+DateTime.Now.ToString()+"'"));

        Console.WriteLine("is contract uptodate ? " + resp.First());
```

Comment: Thanks Attilah, I am also trying to solve exact problem, were you able to keep data type of parameter as date?

Answer (score 2):

We can access RESTful WCF browser services like this

http://localhost:8080/Service/isContractUpToDate/{contractId}/{lastmodifiedDate}

But I think we can't specify DateTime datatype, as per my understanding it should be string only.

Answer (score 1):

I have found [this series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx) to be extremely helpful and rich with examples on how to implement WCF REST services (including query strings and filters as well as calling from client code).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`?startDate=2014-04-11T14:45:00&endDate=2014-05-31T23:59:59`

I'm using this string to send url parameters to a REST service hosted in ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can call it according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728283%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ALFKI')/Orders?$filter=ShippedDate gt datetime'1997-09-22T00:00:00'


datetime'1997-09-22T00:00:00
```